# ASP.NET Website No Publish Option

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms

I took on a project that was developed by another developer.  The client needs a few alterations made to the site so I got the source code and found out it was developed as an ASP.NET Website project (not web application).  Looking at the FTP site, each code behind file is complied down to its dll in the bin folder.

I opened up the web site using Web Developer 2012 Express, made the alterations and even successfully debugged the application and everything looks good.  The problem is I can not figure out how to publish it!  When I build the web site no dlls are generated in the directory structure of the application.  Further, there is not Build menu and thus no Build > Publish option to publish the website.

I've build and deployed major applications using APS.NET MVC but I can't for the life of me figure out how to deploy this simple website project as no dlls are being created.

How does one publish or deploy a website project with no Build > Publish option and no dlls created when Building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a visual studio express thing. I don't have the build menu here at home on express but at work it shows up fine on projects.

Comment: I have VS 2010 ultimate installed on the same machine. I will try opening it up in that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right-clicking on the site in Solution Explorer and observing any possible Publish Site options there?

Failing that, you might try copying the files directly to the site's root folder on the webserver.

Comment: Argh, okay, sounds like its one of those stripped down varieties. Might try just copying the files directly to the web server..

Comment: Was going to suggest you look for a "Copy Web Site" utility, but then saw your note that you have VS2010 ultimate, so I'm sure you'll get it published..